# What's the difference between raw string interpolation and triple quotes in scala

Tags: string, scala, string-interpolation

Scala has triple quoted strings `"""String\nString"""` to use special characters in the string without escaping. Scala 2.10 also added `raw"String\nString"` for the same purpose.

Is there any difference in how `raw""` and `""""""` work? Can they produce different output for the same string?

Comment: The critical insight I got from the answers below is that using the "s" interpolator combined with the "triple quote" interpolator enabled substitution in a static multi-lined template. I was on the verge of writing my own when I googled, saw @som-snytt's answer below and was SO excited. The way to use it is `val template = s"""Hi there, $name! You have $amount credits remaining! Code: ${code}00"""` The curly braces on the last parameter are required because of the immediately following alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Looking at the source for the default interpolators (found here: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/StringContext.scala) it looks like the "raw" interpolator calls the identity function on each letter, so what you put in is what you get out. The biggest difference that you will find is that if you are providing a string literal in your source that includes the quote character, the raw interpolator still won't work. i.e. you can't say

```
raw"this whole "thing" should be one string object"
```

but you can say

```
"""this whole "thing" should be one string object"""
```

So you might be wondering "Why would I ever bother using the raw interpolator then?" and the answer is that the raw interpolator still performs variable substitution. So

```
val helloVar = "hello"
val helloWorldString = raw"""$helloVar, "World"!\n"""
```

Will give you the string "hello, "World"!\n" with the \n not being converted to a newline, and the quotes around the word world.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the part in docs where it says that it also does interpolation.

Comment: For the record, the scaladoc does actually say what it does.  http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/2.11.x/api/2.11.x/index.html#scala.StringContext@raw(args:Any*):String

Comment: Basically, you say that `raw` does what `s` does.  I can `s"""$literal string with substitution"""`. This does not explain the need for `row` anyway.

Comment: @ValentinTihomirov The difference is that the s interpolator still performs escaping since it is not aware that it is in triple quotes. som-snytt 's answer does a nice job of demonstrating and explaining this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25633978/892445

Comment: Here's a fun thing I just ran across. The $ character marks a variable in interpolation, and the end of a line or a string in regex. So triple quoting turns out to be better for regular expressions.

Comment: I think the first point is the main argument cause we can also perform string interpolation with triple quotes by prepending a s - `s""" $myVariable """` - in which case one might wonder what's the difference the raw interpolator and the s interpolator with triple quotes (slightly different question...)

Answer (score 38):

It is surprising that using the s-interpolator turns escapes back on, even when using triple quotes:

```
scala> "hi\nthere."
res5: String =
hi
there.

scala> """hi\nthere."""
res6: String = hi\nthere.

scala> s"""hi\nthere."""
res7: String =
hi
there.
```

The s-interpolator doesn't know that it's processing string parts that were originally triple-quoted.  Hence:

```
scala> raw"""hi\nthere."""
res8: String = hi\nthere.
```

This matters when you're using backslashes in other ways, such as regexes:

```
scala> val n = """\d"""
n: String = \d

scala> s"$n".r
res9: scala.util.matching.Regex = \d

scala> s"\d".r
scala.StringContext$InvalidEscapeException: invalid escape character at index 0 in "\d"
  at scala.StringContext$.loop$1(StringContext.scala:231)
  at scala.StringContext$.replace$1(StringContext.scala:241)
  at scala.StringContext$.treatEscapes0(StringContext.scala:245)
  at scala.StringContext$.treatEscapes(StringContext.scala:190)
  at scala.StringContext$$anonfun$s$1.apply(StringContext.scala:94)
  at scala.StringContext$$anonfun$s$1.apply(StringContext.scala:94)
  at scala.StringContext.standardInterpolator(StringContext.scala:124)
  at scala.StringContext.s(StringContext.scala:94)
  ... 33 elided

scala> s"""\d""".r
scala.StringContext$InvalidEscapeException: invalid escape character at index 0 in "\d"
  at scala.StringContext$.loop$1(StringContext.scala:231)
  at scala.StringContext$.replace$1(StringContext.scala:241)
  at scala.StringContext$.treatEscapes0(StringContext.scala:245)
  at scala.StringContext$.treatEscapes(StringContext.scala:190)
  at scala.StringContext$$anonfun$s$1.apply(StringContext.scala:94)
  at scala.StringContext$$anonfun$s$1.apply(StringContext.scala:94)
  at scala.StringContext.standardInterpolator(StringContext.scala:124)
  at scala.StringContext.s(StringContext.scala:94)
  ... 33 elided

scala> raw"""\d$n""".r
res12: scala.util.matching.Regex = \d\d
```

Comment: That is indeed odd, and not what I would have assumed to be the case. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once. It just saved me several hours. I was getting ready to write my own implementation unaware that I could combine the "s" interpolator with the "triple quote" interpolator! I've been looking for this solution for over a year (and stupidly hard coded a masking tape and bailing wire solution several times).