# Need Regular Expression in scala

Tags: regex, scala

This is my response

```
   scala > val a= """{"string":"{\"data\":{\"id\":\"2c91809f4ef7678b014ef86ee28511c2\",\"unitName\":\"gatlir1\",\"owner\":\"gatlir1\",\"description\":\"gatlir1\",\"nofChairs\":0,\"nofBeds\":0,\"nofApptStartWithInHour\":0,\"nofApptDischargeWithInHour\":0,\"modifiedDateTime\":\"Aug 4, 2015 4:18:13 AM\"},\"status\":\"SUCCESS\",\"message\":\"unit_save\"}"}"""
```

i need to fetch id value from that response in scala. i have stored response in one variable. and i have written regular expression for that and stored in another variable.

Here is the problem , i am getting error.
RegEx:

```
     scala> val b= """{\"id\":\"(\w+)\""""
```

while inserting regex into "b" , i didn't get any error, but while comparing  i am getting error

if i write expression like this

```
          scala> a.matches(b)
```

error:

```
  java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition
   {\"id\":\"(\w+)\"
   at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Pattern.java:3157)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2134)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1696)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(Pattern.java:1133)
   at java.lang.String.matches(String.java:2109)
```

could any one help me in this..

Comment: `matches()` requires a full string match. You need to escape the `{` properly and add `.*` at the end of the pattern.

Comment: """\"id\":\"(\w+)\.*"""" like this..

Answer (score 6):

Why are you using regular expressions here? Just read the JSON. JSON is not a regular language, and can not be easily described with regex.

Here's one of many library's that will parse JSON for Scala https://github.com/json4s/json4s

It'll also make accessing any of the other objects inside much easier.

Comment: Actually, that id is dymanic value, i need to use this value in next request, so with regex , i am fetching it and using it in next request.

Comment: +1. Regexes are only going to be painful here.  @RaviVaranasi there's no reason you can't use a JSON library to parse out whatever value you need for the next request.

Comment: I have to use regex or json parsing?

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the `{`:

```
val b= """\{\"id\":\"(\w+)\""""
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. i have removed { , now  i am getting response as "Boolean = false" , i need to get true. what can i change there?

Comment: @RaviVaranasi when dealing with JSONs, regex is not good usually. Pick a library that parses JSONs and work with it. If you still want to use regexes, you should use `find` instead.

Comment: im using this expression in my code .check(regex(("""\"id\":\"(\w+)\"""")).find.exists.saveAs("id"))

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fixed code:

```
val a= """{"string":"{"data":{"id":"2c91809f4ef7678b014ef86ee28511c2","unitName":"gatlir1","owner":"gatlir1","description":"gatlir1","nofChairs":0,"nofBeds":0,"nofApptStartWithInHour":0,"nofApptDischargeWithInHour":0,"modifiedDateTime":"Aug 4, 2015 4:18:13 AM"},"status":"SUCCESS","message":"unit_save"}"}"""
val b= """\{"id":"(\w+)""".r
val allMatches = b.findAllMatchIn(a)
allMatches.foreach { m =>
     println(m.group(1))
}
```

It prints: `2c91809f4ef7678b014ef86ee28511c2`.

See [demo](https://ideone.com/E36jno)

Note you do not have to escape double quotes inside `"""` quoted strings (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25633265/3832970)).

Comment: Thank you so much, but if i have write same code in gatling tool, i am getting this error ---- Errors --------------------------------------------------------------------
> No attribute named 'id' is defined                                  2 (66.67%)
> regex(\{"id":"(\w+)).find(0).exists, found nothing                  1 (33.33%)
================================================================================

Comment: same regex i have used in my code, .check(regex(("""\{"id":"(\w+)""")).find.exists.saveAs("id"))

Comment: Try `.check(regex("""\{"id":"(\w+)""").whatever.saveAs("id"))`.